# How to correctly compile a quarto website with nested folder structure?

Tags: quarto

I am experimenting with `quarto` to see how I can create a website. These are the steps that I have followed so far:

1. Open RStudio (RStudio Server 2022.02.0 Build 443)
2. Go to **File** > **New Project...** > **New Directory** > **Quarto Website** > type **Directory name:** > **Create Project**
3. Go to **Build** > **Render Website**

This works fine! However, when I try to add a section for blog, the website doesn't compile correctly. Here's what I did:

1. Create a **blog** folder under root
2. Create a file **blog/index.qmd**
3. Create a **blog/posts** folder
4. Create a **blog/posts/test-post** folder
5. Add files **index.qmd** and **featured.jpg** to **blog/posts/test-post** folder

Run this code in R console to add **featured.jpg** file:

```
download.file(
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/August_Macke_-_Three_girls_in_yellow_straw_hats_I_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg", 
  "blog/posts/test-post/featured.jpg"
)
```

Here are the contents of the **blog/index.qmd** file:

```
---
title: This is my blog.
listing:
  contents: posts
  type: default
---
```

Here are the contents of the **blog/posts/test-post/index.qmd** file:

```
---
title: My first blog post.
image: featured.jpg
---
```

Here are the contents of the `_quarto.yml` file:

```
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "test-quarto-web"
  navbar:
    background: primary
    left:
      - href: index.qmd
        text: Home
      - about.qmd
      - href: blog/index.qmd
        text: Blog

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css

editor: visual
```

After I render the website and click on the **Blog menu**, this is what I see:

[image]

How can I fix this issue? I believe there is some problem with the file path, but I couldn't figure out how to fix this!

Comment: I don't see any R programming in this question.

Comment: I replicated your file structure and it worked for me (I'm using VS Code, not RStudio). Do you know your Quarto version? Running `quarto --version`  tells me that my version is 0.9.647.

Comment: Running `quarto --version` in the terminal returns `bash: quarto: command not found`! This is what I found on the quarto website: "Alternatively, there is a version of Quarto built-in to RStudio that you can activate from R Markdown Preferences." I used this feature. I didn't install quarto myself. How can I check the version of quarto that comes bundled with RStudio?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get the version used in RStudio, but I copied your directory structure to my RStudio installation (version 2022.07 build 548) and the post and image also appared.

Comment: Just want to be sure that I'm using the correct directory structure:
`project_root (contains _quarto.yml, .gitignore, about.qmd, [blog], x.Rproj, index.qmd, styles.css)`, then `blog (contains index.qmd and [posts])`, then `posts (contains [test-post])`, then `test-post (contains featured.jpg and index.qmd)`

The listings file is the index.qmd inside the `[blog]` directory.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting! I see that you are using version 2022.07, but in my case it's 2022.02. If possible, can you try using the previous RStudio version and see if you can reproduce my problem? Also, you are right about the folder structure.

Comment: I am using the docker image with Google Cloud, so updating RStudio server doesn't seem like an option (at least not yet!). As I understand it, updating quarto might fix this problem. If I install quarto, will it interfere with the quarto version that comes bundled with RStudio and lead to more problems? Just curious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246303/discussion-between-ashirwad-and-lucas-a-meyer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this is frequently due to using an old version of Quarto. As Quarto is nearing release, there are improvements happening daily.

To install the latest version from Quarto, follow the instructions [here](https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-quarto/#download-and-install-quarto-using-deb-file). Use the "Latest Quarto version" tab.

If you install a new version, RStudio Desktop will recognize it.